# javascript function only works with the first included function

Tags: javascript

I have the following function (`onButtonClick`) when the button is clicked only the first function works. All the included functions work if I only have one of them in the button function.

I have also tried the on button click function this way as well. Still does not work.

```
setProjectData() && getProjectData() && window.location.href='support_page.html';
```

Any ideas on what I may be missing?

```
<span class="profile_container_right">
    <a onclick='onButtonClick()'; return true;"; ><img src="images/bSUPPORT.png"/></a>
</span>

<script>
    /* on button click */           
    function onButtonClick(){
        setProjectData();
        getProjectData();
        window.location.href='support_page.html';
    }

    function setProjectData() {
    // --- set local storage project descriptions ---
    vProjectName=‘The Project Name’;
            localStorage.setItem('xProjectName', vProjectName);
            return true;
    }

    function getProjectData() {
    // --- get local storage project descriptions ---
            vProjectName = localStorage.getItem('xProjectName');
            alert('you entered the GET project data function ='+vProjectName);
            return true;    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Did you look at the browser console for any errors? 2. What do you mean by don't work?

Comment: Do you have curly quotes in your source code for that first line in `setProjectData`, or did they just get introduced when you copied the code here?

Comment: Also, can you indent that first line of code there? It isn't substantial enough to allow an edit, but it is not very readable

Comment: Also, your question is a bit vague to me. If the first function works, doesn't that mean that everything works, since it calls the other two? Or are you saying that only `setProjectData()` works?

Answer (score 3):

First issue is the use of quotes in the onclick binding:

```
onclick='onButtonClick()'; return true;";
```

The correct syntax for onclick is `onclick="yourFunctionCall();"` for example:

```
onclick="onButtonClick(); return true;"
```

Second issue is your use of quotes in the setProjectData function:

```
vProjectName=‘The Project Name’;
```

Change to single quotes or double quotes:

```
vProjectName="The Project Name";
```

With these syntax issues fixed your code should execute as expected.

Side note use `var` to declare variables within a function to make them adhere to the scope of the function. Declaring a js variable without the `var` exposes the variable globally.

Comment: I made corrections to the single and double quotes, but I think the main problem was an two undefined values in my original code which I also corrected. Everything is working properly now.  Thanks everyone.